# Dynamically embed pictures and images to page based on Meta Data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, page-layout, content-query-web-part

What is the best way to pull field/column data and insert this content into a page?

I have created the list with Product Meta Data and have associated product descriptions and thumbnail images with each of these tags. I would like the page to query this list based on a selection criteria (Product Name) and display a Product Title, Product Description, and Image on the top of the page. See attached for sample.

[image: Page Concept Sample]

I know I can hard-code all of this information onto the page, but I would prefer to make it Dynamic from the list to allow batch alteration in the future as we have more than 200 products.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Site: SharePoint 2010
Access: Site Collection Admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use Content Query Web Part with custom XSL template to get the desired look and feel. In CQWP you can define the actual query, including pointing it to show items from your new list.

Edit `\Style Library\XSL Style Sheets\ItemStyle.xsl` and copy existing template, rename your copy (change name and match properties) and modify the HTML it provides. You can add additional fields in the template and they will automatically be shown when configuring CQWP.

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb447557(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but I wanted to make sure there were no other alternatives. 

Is it better to create a separate ItemStyle or complete the modifications in-line?

Comment: I guess the "correct" answer is to create separate ItemStyle file and reference that from the Web Part. It requires few extra steps though: exporting the web part, modifying the XML  to reference new ItemStyle file and importing it back in.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom page layout for that.

Then create the 200 pages and configure the fields (the propertise of the pages) that the page layout uses to do the queries.

Do the queries either with a Search WebPart or a Content Query WebPart.

Comment: Is there an advantage to putting the field in the Page Layout Properties instead of creating a WebPart Filter?

Comment: The Page Layout give you the entire page - the webpart is only a part of it.